# How to use a temporary table variable (e.g. @temp) for holding the result of sp_msforeachdb

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am basically trying to find out all the table of all the databases present in the SQL SERVER by using sp_msforeachdb.

If I write `exec sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS DatabaseNames,* from [?].sys.tables'`

I will get the result well but for every Database, a seperate record set will be created.

Now if I use

```
CREATE TABLE #DBINFO
(
            DbName NVARCHAR(255)
            ,ObjectID NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #DBINFO
exec sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS DatabaseNames,ObjectID  from [?].sys.tables'

SELECT * FROM #DBINFO
```

This works fine.

However, if I do

```
Declare @DBINFO Table(DbName NVARCHAR(255),ObjectID NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @DBINFO
    exec sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS DatabaseNames,ObjectID  from [?].sys.tables'

    SELECT * FROM @DBINFO
```

It does not accept

Moreover, If I do

```
;With CTE AS
(
  exec sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS DatabaseNames,* from [?].sys.tables'
)

Select * from CTE
```

, it throws error ( Presently I donot remember that).

Question is

1) Is it possible to do the same stuff using a table variable

2) Is it possible to get the same thing done using CTE?

SQL SERVER 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Yes, you just need to use the proper names for your columns (`object_id`, not `ObjectID`):

```
Declare @DBINFO Table(DbName NVARCHAR(255),ObjectID NVARCHAR(255)) 
INSERT INTO @DBINFO 
exec sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS DatabaseNames,object_id  from [?].sys.tables' 
SELECT * FROM @DBINFO
```

2) No